Switch Symbol on a Datasheet Block Diagram
I have seen quite a few times in datasheets this switch symbol (at the red circle on the attached picture) on block diagrams. Do you know what is his formal name and if it isn’t a “simple” switch (like a standard electromechanical switch) what exactly is.

Image source: ON Semiconductor - MC14051B, MC14052B, MC15053B datasheet

You can find it discussed here. And here.
